# How can you detect key presses in vb console mode?

Tags: vb.net, console, key

I wanted to make a program involving a menu at the start but instead of using the typical select case I wanted to do it differently.

I wanted it to give the user some options and then they would use the arrow keys to move a little arrow next to the options.

Finally you press enter and then you would advance to the next screen that you selected. I have been searching the web but I could only find this kind of stuff in form mode, not console. If this isn't possible let me know and I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: You should be able to do this by using the [`Console.SetCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: In combination with `Console.ReadKey(True)`, which will read the key pressed but not echo it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is with a menu class that will print out the menu and highlight the item number passed to it:

```
Class Menu
    Private MenuList As New List(Of String)
    Public ReadOnly Property LineCount As Integer
        Get
            Return MenuList.Count
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub CreateNewMenu(strings As IEnumerable(Of String))
        MenuList.Clear()
        For Each s In strings
            MenuList.Add(s)
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Sub PrintMenu(highlight As Integer)
        If highlight < 0 OrElse highlight > MenuList.Count - 1 Then
            Throw New Exception("Invalid menu index")
        End If
        For I = 0 To MenuList.Count - 1
            If I = highlight Then
                SwapColors()
                Console.WriteLine(MenuList(I))
                Console.ResetColor()
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(MenuList(I))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub SwapColors()
        Dim temp = Console.BackgroundColor
        Console.BackgroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor
        Console.ForegroundColor = temp
    End Sub
End Class
```

To use it would look like this:

```
Dim MainMenu As New Menu
MainMenu.CreateNewMenu(
    {
        "Option A",
        "Option B",
        "Option C"
    })
Dim CurrentItem As Integer = 0
Dim CurrentKey As ConsoleKey
While CurrentKey <> ConsoleKey.Enter
    Console.Clear()
    MainMenu.PrintMenu(CurrentItem)
    CurrentKey = Console.ReadKey(True).Key
    If CurrentKey = ConsoleKey.UpArrow Then
        CurrentItem -= 1
    ElseIf CurrentKey = ConsoleKey.DownArrow Then
        CurrentItem += 1
    End If
    CurrentItem = (CurrentItem + MainMenu.LineCount) Mod MainMenu.LineCount
End While
```

This will use inverted colors to highlight the selected item, but this can easily be changed to add an indicator when writing the item to the console, if desired.

When the while loop exits `CurrentItem` will hold the 0-based index of the selected menu item.

One advantage of this approach is that you can have several collections of menus that will allow you to show specific ones based on the selection.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how do I add a second screen when you press enter. (I am quite new to this stuff :) )

Comment: Create a new menu and clear the console first before running the PrintMenu method