# A Sub Procedure holds a list, but only the first item is changed through SetCursorPosition

Tags: vb.net, console-application

```
Module Module1

Dim MenuList As New List(Of String)

Function LineCount() As Integer
    Return MenuList.Count
End Function

Sub CreateNewMenu(strings() As String)
    For Each s In strings
        MenuList.Add(s)
    Next
End Sub

Sub PrintMenu(highlight As Integer)
    For I = 0 To MenuList.Count - 1
        If I = highlight Then
            SwapColors()
            Console.WriteLine(MenuList(I))
            Console.ResetColor()
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(MenuList(I))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub SwapColors()
    Dim temp = Console.BackgroundColor
    Console.BackgroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor
    Console.ForegroundColor = temp
End Sub

Sub Main()
    CreateNewMenu(
        {
            "Option A",
            "Option B",
            "Option C"
        })
    Dim CurrentItem As Integer = 0
    Dim CurrentKey As ConsoleKey
    While CurrentKey <> ConsoleKey.Enter
        Console.Clear()

        PrintMenu(CurrentItem)

        'Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 10)

        'Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 11)

        'Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 12)

        CurrentKey = Console.ReadKey(True).Key
        Select Case CurrentKey

            Case ConsoleKey.DownArrow
                CurrentItem += 1

            Case ConsoleKey.UpArrow
                CurrentItem -= 1

        End Select
        CurrentItem = (CurrentItem + LineCount()) Mod LineCount()
    End While

End Sub

End Module
```

This is a Code, A changed Post written 2014. The following link should be the source. [How can you detect key presses in vb console mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893291/how-can-you-detect-key-presses-in-vb-console-mode)

The PrintMenu Procedure spotted in the Main Sub Procedure is the line i try to Change with a SetCursorPosition command.

I am able to Change the Output to be screened on row 10 line 10. But only for the Option A.

What has to be done, to manage every item that can be listed on Screen? I want to change the row and line for every item through the PrintMenu Procedure.

Comment: Where did you put the call to `SetCursorPosition`?  Can you show that?

Comment: It can be put above the PrintMenu(CurrentItem), between Console.Clear() and PrintMenu(CurrentItem) in the Sub Main() Procedure. If possible you can copy it from the three comment lines. One comment line holds the SetCursorPosition(10, 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the cursor position is set for the first item in the list but when `WriteLine` is called, the cursor position is reset to the next line on column = 0.  I would change the `PrintMenu` method to accept the left and top cursor positiion.  Something like this (untested):

```
Sub PrintMenu(highlight As Integer, left As Integer, top As Integer)

    For I = 0 To MenuList.Count - 1

        Console.CursorLeft = left
        Console.CursorTop = top + I      'Use loop variable to adjust top position

        If I = highlight Then
            SwapColors()
            Console.Write(MenuList(I))   'Changed to use Write instead
            Console.ResetColor()
        Else
            Console.Write(MenuList(I))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: With your adds, and the Change of the PrintMenu(CurrentItem) to PrintMenu(CurrentItem, 10 ,10) it fits to be a solution. The Output now Matches all three lines with a starting Position line 10 row 10. I am in very good mood with your answer for further VB.NET investigations. Thank's.